# CSS Position Sticky Sidebar Within Grid

Tags: html, css, css-position, css-grid

I have a simple page in which I want a sticky header and a sticky sidebar. Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3z7j059t/1/) and here is the same code:

```css
#top {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 50px;
  grid-template-columns: max-content 1fr;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 900px;
}

.sidebar {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div id="top">
  sticky header
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar">
    sticky sidebar
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus at ipsum mi. Integer laoreet a nisl quis imperdiet. Etiam sed ligula rutrum, viverra arcu vitae, mattis lectus. Aliquam rutrum eros id quam sodales volutpat. Suspendisse sed neque ut mauris
      luctus hendrerit. Suspendisse auctor aliquam rutrum. Sed sodales placerat est. Donec vel elit vitae ipsum ultrices tristique. Nulla auctor, dolor at porta laoreet, ex nisi auctor orci, in posuere enim arcu at tortor. Etiam sed ante mattis sem pharetra
      condimentum. Nullam a eros nec metus feugiat tincidunt vel sed lectus. Nunc accumsan nisi sit amet auctor rhoncus. Vestibulum diam risus, sodales non diam a, tristique ullamcorper erat.
    </p>
    <p>
      Aliquam posuere libero at felis maximus, quis pulvinar diam dictum. Integer id nisi non turpis bibendum suscipit. Duis pellentesque leo vitae elit mollis malesuada. Duis eget magna et odio mattis bibendum. Ut et rutrum diam, quis luctus mi. Duis in molestie
      elit. Nullam consequat turpis velit, sit amet venenatis tellus bibendum non. Etiam iaculis luctus sem, et aliquam nisl commodo et. In consectetur ac nibh ac porttitor. Nulla euismod facilisis faucibus. Phasellus sed risus convallis, elementum est
      nec, euismod lorem. Nulla sodales auctor dapibus. Curabitur euismod neque dolor, at sagittis arcu congue ultrices. Morbi nec finibus tortor.
    </p>
    <p>
      Aliquam vestibulum dictum nisi non sollicitudin. Integer ac magna viverra, cursus lorem quis, interdum ex. Phasellus id neque pulvinar, dignissim augue ut, lobortis leo. Duis sed elit et ipsum auctor convallis. Donec non orci suscipit, eleifend tellus
      pretium, vehicula turpis. Mauris et justo et est cursus accumsan et vel elit. In egestas lobortis imperdiet. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus
      et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Etiam dictum vel lorem in varius. Etiam accumsan nibh at ex mollis, id porta leo sodales. Suspendisse mauris urna, faucibus in turpis et, porttitor lobortis lectus. Cras facilisis feugiat tortor sed laoreet. Nam
      cursus malesuada lorem sed bibendum. Sed dapibus, mi vel elementum vehicula, augue massa pulvinar erat, vitae rutrum eros nisi sed neque.
    </p>
    <p>
      Nulla sodales lectus vitae urna ullamcorper, eu mattis lacus iaculis. Praesent eleifend eu sem nec aliquet. Pellentesque consequat nisl ac odio efficitur, vitae interdum sapien gravida. Proin sed commodo leo. Quisque sem sem, euismod id sapien eget, fermentum
      consectetur turpis. Praesent aliquam eros id ipsum vehicula, aliquam pellentesque massa pellentesque. Etiam nec elit arcu. Donec eget ullamcorper nisl, in porta nibh. In non ante id elit tincidunt convallis. Suspendisse sit amet dictum sapien, vel
      lobortis mi. Mauris eu pharetra ante. Morbi vestibulum orci at augue pulvinar iaculis. Vestibulum quis dui et odio tristique laoreet eget id augue.
    </p>
    <p>
      Nulla finibus lorem in risus efficitur, at cursus nunc molestie. In pellentesque quis quam et sollicitudin. Mauris at turpis felis. Nulla facilisi. Cras pellentesque malesuada felis, sit amet dapibus lectus efficitur auctor. Mauris dictum eu nisl non
      commodo. Quisque at risus eget quam dictum aliquet. Curabitur malesuada magna et efficitur bibendum. Curabitur ultrices luctus lorem. Vivamus sodales elit quis metus mattis, pretium semper mi finibus.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The sticky header works fine.

The sticky sidebar does not work. The sidebar is in a containing element that sets the CSS grid, and is centered with a max-width. I have read that [sticky sticks to its nearest scrolling ancestor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position), so I assume this is not working because the `body` is scrolling and not the container div, but I'm not sure what to do about this.

If I do something like `height: 100px` on the container div I end up with a scrollbar on that div rather than the body. I want the scroll on the body.

If I used a `fixed` position on the sidebar, the grid breaks (the content div now spans 100% of the container) and I would have to know the height of the top sticky bar in order to set the offset on the scrollbar. If the height of the top bar varies this won't work.

What is the solution to this?

Comment: What about an other div within the sidebar and give that the position sticky with a top of 50px? And of course remove the current styles of the .sidebar :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `align-self: flex-start` to *override* the default *stretch* behaviour of `sidebar`( because it is a *grid item*)

Now you can *explicitly* set 100vh `height` to the `sidebar` - see demo below without `grid-gap` and / or `margin` or `padding`

```css
#top {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  /*grid-gap: 50px;*/
  grid-template-columns: max-content 1fr;
  /* margin-top: 50px;*/
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 900px;
}

.sidebar {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  /* ADDED */
  align-self: flex-start; /* override the default stretch */
  height: 100vh; /* set a fixed height */
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div id="top">
  sticky header
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar">
    sticky sidebar
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus at ipsum mi. Integer laoreet a nisl quis imperdiet. Etiam sed ligula rutrum, viverra arcu vitae, mattis lectus. Aliquam rutrum eros id quam sodales volutpat. Suspendisse sed neque ut mauris
      luctus hendrerit. Suspendisse auctor aliquam rutrum. Sed sodales placerat est. Donec vel elit vitae ipsum ultrices tristique. Nulla auctor, dolor at porta laoreet, ex nisi auctor orci, in posuere enim arcu at tortor. Etiam sed ante mattis sem pharetra
      condimentum. Nullam a eros nec metus feugiat tincidunt vel sed lectus. Nunc accumsan nisi sit amet auctor rhoncus. Vestibulum diam risus, sodales non diam a, tristique ullamcorper erat.
    </p>
    <p>
      Aliquam posuere libero at felis maximus, quis pulvinar diam dictum. Integer id nisi non turpis bibendum suscipit. Duis pellentesque leo vitae elit mollis malesuada. Duis eget magna et odio mattis bibendum. Ut et rutrum diam, quis luctus mi. Duis in molestie
      elit. Nullam consequat turpis velit, sit amet venenatis tellus bibendum non. Etiam iaculis luctus sem, et aliquam nisl commodo et. In consectetur ac nibh ac porttitor. Nulla euismod facilisis faucibus. Phasellus sed risus convallis, elementum est
      nec, euismod lorem. Nulla sodales auctor dapibus. Curabitur euismod neque dolor, at sagittis arcu congue ultrices. Morbi nec finibus tortor.
    </p>
    <p>
      Aliquam vestibulum dictum nisi non sollicitudin. Integer ac magna viverra, cursus lorem quis, interdum ex. Phasellus id neque pulvinar, dignissim augue ut, lobortis leo. Duis sed elit et ipsum auctor convallis. Donec non orci suscipit, eleifend tellus
      pretium, vehicula turpis. Mauris et justo et est cursus accumsan et vel elit. In egestas lobortis imperdiet. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus
      et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Etiam dictum vel lorem in varius. Etiam accumsan nibh at ex mollis, id porta leo sodales. Suspendisse mauris urna, faucibus in turpis et, porttitor lobortis lectus. Cras facilisis feugiat tortor sed laoreet. Nam
      cursus malesuada lorem sed bibendum. Sed dapibus, mi vel elementum vehicula, augue massa pulvinar erat, vitae rutrum eros nisi sed neque.
    </p>
    <p>
      Nulla sodales lectus vitae urna ullamcorper, eu mattis lacus iaculis. Praesent eleifend eu sem nec aliquet. Pellentesque consequat nisl ac odio efficitur, vitae interdum sapien gravida. Proin sed commodo leo. Quisque sem sem, euismod id sapien eget, fermentum
      consectetur turpis. Praesent aliquam eros id ipsum vehicula, aliquam pellentesque massa pellentesque. Etiam nec elit arcu. Donec eget ullamcorper nisl, in porta nibh. In non ante id elit tincidunt convallis. Suspendisse sit amet dictum sapien, vel
      lobortis mi. Mauris eu pharetra ante. Morbi vestibulum orci at augue pulvinar iaculis. Vestibulum quis dui et odio tristique laoreet eget id augue.
    </p>
    <p>
      Nulla finibus lorem in risus efficitur, at cursus nunc molestie. In pellentesque quis quam et sollicitudin. Mauris at turpis felis. Nulla facilisi. Cras pellentesque malesuada felis, sit amet dapibus lectus efficitur auctor. Mauris dictum eu nisl non
      commodo. Quisque at risus eget quam dictum aliquet. Curabitur malesuada magna et efficitur bibendum. Curabitur ultrices luctus lorem. Vivamus sodales elit quis metus mattis, pretium semper mi finibus.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Adding back the `grid-gap`, `margin` and `padding` - you can adjust the *explicit* height set on the `sidebar` - see demo below:

```css
#top {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 50px;
  grid-template-columns: max-content 1fr;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 900px;
}

.sidebar {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  /* ADDED */
  align-self: flex-start; /* override the default stretch */
  height: calc(100vh - 30px); /* set a fixed height */
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div id="top">
  sticky header
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar">
    sticky sidebar
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus at ipsum mi. Integer laoreet a nisl quis imperdiet. Etiam sed ligula rutrum, viverra arcu vitae, mattis lectus. Aliquam rutrum eros id quam sodales volutpat. Suspendisse sed neque ut mauris
      luctus hendrerit. Suspendisse auctor aliquam rutrum. Sed sodales placerat est. Donec vel elit vitae ipsum ultrices tristique. Nulla auctor, dolor at porta laoreet, ex nisi auctor orci, in posuere enim arcu at tortor. Etiam sed ante mattis sem pharetra
      condimentum. Nullam a eros nec metus feugiat tincidunt vel sed lectus. Nunc accumsan nisi sit amet auctor rhoncus. Vestibulum diam risus, sodales non diam a, tristique ullamcorper erat.
    </p>
    <p>
      Aliquam posuere libero at felis maximus, quis pulvinar diam dictum. Integer id nisi non turpis bibendum suscipit. Duis pellentesque leo vitae elit mollis malesuada. Duis eget magna et odio mattis bibendum. Ut et rutrum diam, quis luctus mi. Duis in molestie
      elit. Nullam consequat turpis velit, sit amet venenatis tellus bibendum non. Etiam iaculis luctus sem, et aliquam nisl commodo et. In consectetur ac nibh ac porttitor. Nulla euismod facilisis faucibus. Phasellus sed risus convallis, elementum est
      nec, euismod lorem. Nulla sodales auctor dapibus. Curabitur euismod neque dolor, at sagittis arcu congue ultrices. Morbi nec finibus tortor.
    </p>
    <p>
      Aliquam vestibulum dictum nisi non sollicitudin. Integer ac magna viverra, cursus lorem quis, interdum ex. Phasellus id neque pulvinar, dignissim augue ut, lobortis leo. Duis sed elit et ipsum auctor convallis. Donec non orci suscipit, eleifend tellus
      pretium, vehicula turpis. Mauris et justo et est cursus accumsan et vel elit. In egestas lobortis imperdiet. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus
      et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Etiam dictum vel lorem in varius. Etiam accumsan nibh at ex mollis, id porta leo sodales. Suspendisse mauris urna, faucibus in turpis et, porttitor lobortis lectus. Cras facilisis feugiat tortor sed laoreet. Nam
      cursus malesuada lorem sed bibendum. Sed dapibus, mi vel elementum vehicula, augue massa pulvinar erat, vitae rutrum eros nisi sed neque.
    </p>
    <p>
      Nulla sodales lectus vitae urna ullamcorper, eu mattis lacus iaculis. Praesent eleifend eu sem nec aliquet. Pellentesque consequat nisl ac odio efficitur, vitae interdum sapien gravida. Proin sed commodo leo. Quisque sem sem, euismod id sapien eget, fermentum
      consectetur turpis. Praesent aliquam eros id ipsum vehicula, aliquam pellentesque massa pellentesque. Etiam nec elit arcu. Donec eget ullamcorper nisl, in porta nibh. In non ante id elit tincidunt convallis. Suspendisse sit amet dictum sapien, vel
      lobortis mi. Mauris eu pharetra ante. Morbi vestibulum orci at augue pulvinar iaculis. Vestibulum quis dui et odio tristique laoreet eget id augue.
    </p>
    <p>
      Nulla finibus lorem in risus efficitur, at cursus nunc molestie. In pellentesque quis quam et sollicitudin. Mauris at turpis felis. Nulla facilisi. Cras pellentesque malesuada felis, sit amet dapibus lectus efficitur auctor. Mauris dictum eu nisl non
      commodo. Quisque at risus eget quam dictum aliquet. Curabitur malesuada magna et efficitur bibendum. Curabitur ultrices luctus lorem. Vivamus sodales elit quis metus mattis, pretium semper mi finibus.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```